# How to assign values from one object to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to assign values from the below "details" object to the each "model" in the "formFields" array.

**Here is the details object**

```
const details = {
    criteriaName: "hello",
    criteriaType: "type a",
    description: "world"
}
```

**Here is the formFields array**

From the above details object I was trying to assign each value from each key to the each model from the formFields array

```
const formFields = [
    {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "columns": 2,
        "fields": {
            "criteriaName": {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "Criteria Name",
                "id": 'criteriaName',
                "model": "",
                "required": true,
                "show": true,
                "rules": [
                    v => !!v || 'Criteria Name is required',
                ]
            },
            "criteriaType": {
                "type": "select",
                "label": "Criteria type",
                "id": "criteriaType",
                "options": ['Dependent', 'Independent', 'Static'],
                "model": "",
                "required": true,
                "rules": [
                    v => !!v || 'Criteria Type is required',
                ],
                "show": true,
            },
        }
    },
    {
        'title': "Title 2",
        "columns": 1,
        "fields": {
            "description": {
                "type": "description_notes",
                "label": "Description",
                "id": "description",
                "required": false,
                "model": '',
                "show": true,
            }
        }
    }
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

```
formFields.forEach((form) => {
    if (form.fields.criteriaName) form.fields.criteriaName.model = details.criteriaName;
    if (form.fields.criteriaType) form.fields.criteriaType.model = details.criteriaType;
    if (form.fields.description) form.fields.description.model = details.description;
})
```

This would make changes in original array.
You can read more about forEach [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

if you want to create a new array with changes you can use:

```
let newFormFields = formFields.map((form) => {
    if (form.fields.criteriaName) form.fields.criteriaName.model = details.criteriaName;
    if (form.fields.criteriaType) form.fields.criteriaType.model = details.criteriaType;
    if (form.fields.description) form.fields.description.model = details.description;

    return form;
});
```

and you can read more about map [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow. The following code will probably do what you're asking for. It is a bit much to explain all the details but you can ask in the comments and read some of the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)

```js
const details = {
  criteriaName: 'hello',
  criteriaType: 'type a',
  description: 'world',
};

const formFields = [
  {
    title: 'Title 1',
    fields: {
      criteriaName: {
        id: 'criteriaName',
        model: '',
      },
      criteriaType: {
        id: 'criteriaType',
        model: '',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 2',
    fields: {
      description: {
        id: 'description',
        model: '',
      },
      nonExisting: {
        id: 'nonExisting',
        model: 'this will not be replaced',
      },
    },
  },
];

const result = formFields.map((formField) => ({
  ...formField,
  fields: Object.entries(formField.fields).reduce(
    (fields, [key, value]) =>
      details[key]
        ? {
            ...fields,
            [key]: { ...value, model: details[key] },
          }
        : fields,
    formField.fields,
  ),
}));

console.log(result);
```